# How does the tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.DatasetV1Adapter work?

Tags: python, function, csv, tensorflow

I am trying to wrap my head around ML and AI using TensorFlow. There is an example problem on the website which discusses the processing of .CSV data. The .CVS data is said to have been taken from the titanic and essentially contains categorical and numerical features that will be used to label a passenger as dead or alive.

First of all, if anyone know or has any resources or references that discusses that example in more detail than is done on the [TensorFlow website](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/tutorials/load_data/csv), please could you kindly refer me to that?

Secondly, to my more important question. There is a method which is used in the example to pack the individual numeric data into a single numeric key while maintaining the categorical column as is.

The function used to do this is as bellow:

```
class PackNumericFeatures(object):
    def __init__(self, names):
        self.names = names

    def __call__(self, features, labels):
        numeric_freatures = [features.pop(name) for name in self.names]
        numeric_features = [tf.cast(feat, tf.float32) for feat in numeric_freatures]
        numeric_features = tf.stack(numeric_features, axis=-1)
        features['numeric'] = numeric_features

        return features, labels
```

The above function is called like this:

```
NUMERIC_FEATURES = ['age','n_siblings_spouses','parch', 'fare']

packed_train_data = raw_train_data.map(PackNumericFeatures(NUMERIC_FEATURES))
```

The output `packed_train_data` looks something like this:

```
sex                 : [b'male' b'female' b'female' b'female' b'male']
class               : [b'Third' b'First' b'Third' b'First' b'Third']
deck                : [b'unknown' b'C' b'unknown' b'C' b'unknown']
embark_town         : [b'Southampton' b'Cherbourg' b'Southampton' b'Southampton' b'Queenstown']
alone               : [b'n' b'n' b'y' b'n' b'y']
numeric             : [[22.      1.      0.      7.25  ]
 [38.      1.      0.     71.2833]
 [26.      0.      0.      7.925 ]
 [35.      1.      0.     53.1   ]
 [28.      0.      0.      8.4583]]
```

The above output is produced by passing a single batch of data (i.e. `packed_train_data`) to the function:

```
def show_batch(dataset):
    for batch, head in dataset.take(1):
        for labels, value in batch.items():
            print("{:20s}: {}".format(labels, value.numpy()))
```

like this:

```
show_batch(packed_train_data)
```

What I do not understand is how the `map` function is working to generate that output. More generally I don't get how the call containing the `map` function is interacting with the `PackNumericFeatures(object)` class.

I know this problem is specific but any help would be appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: 1) you should link the website you referenced so we can look at it too. 2) what do you not understand exactly? Have you tried printing "features" and "labels" in the `__call__` function to get an idea of what is happening?

Comment: Thanks Ian, I have included the website as you mentioned. I printed the output of ```__call__ ```. Printing `features` gives an ordered dictionary containing Tensors which corresponds to all the features being considered (i.e. CATEGORICAL_FEATURES plus `NUMERIC_FEATURES`). While label is just a single Tensor.

Comment: > Printing features gives an ordered dictionary containing Tensors which corresponds to all the features being considered (i.e. CATEGORICAL_FEATURES plus NUMERIC_FEATURES). While label is just a single Tensor

Awesome. So what do you not understand exactly?

Comment: I think I have found what I am looking for. My misunderstanding lies in what the `.map` function does. The `.map(f)` function is a method of the class `dataset`. It is designed to accept a function and return new data that has been effected by the function passed to it.

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov that's a completely separate question. I'd say open a new thread